# I encountered Shadowed name: 'props' (no-shadowed-variable)tslint(1)

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and encountered warning from tslint saying "Shadowed name: 'props' (no-shadowed-variable)tslint(1)". I really cannot solve that thus I really need your help.

```
 return (
                    <DropdownMenuPortal
                        children={children}
                        anchorEl={anchorEl}
                        container={document.body}
                        isOpen={menuIsOpen}
                    />
                );
            },
            ValueContainer: this.ValueContainer,
            MultiValue: this.MultiValue,
            SingleValue: this.SingleValue,
            Placeholder: this.Placeholder,
            Control: this.Control,
            **//Here I have that issue**
            Menu: (**props**: MenuProps<OptionType> & { innerProps: { onMouseDown(): void } }) => {
                const {
                    selectProps: { options, filterOption, inputValue },
                    children,
                    getValue,
                    setValue,
                    innerProps: { onMouseDown },
                } = props;
                const value = getValue() as OptionsType<OptionType>;

                const showSelectAllBtn = value.length < options.length;
                const showClearAllBtn = !!value.length;

                const onSelectAll = () => {
                    const filteredOptions = options.filter(option =>
                        filterOption(option as any, inputValue)
                    );
                    setValue([...value, ...filteredOptions], setValueAction);
                };
```

Comment: use **this.props** instead of **props**. Also share proper error message that you have seen on your screen.

Answer (score 0):

The warning appears because you redefined the same variable multiple times.

If you really need to turn off this warning, add this to your tslint rules:

```
"rules": {
     "no-shadowed-variable": false
}
```